# Push rejected, failed to compile PHP (HHVM) app

Tags: php, git, heroku, hhvm, hacklang

I need to develop a web app using HHVM and Hacklang on Heroku. The problem is when I `git push` to Heroku master, I got this error message:

```
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP (HHVM) app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to hacklang.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hacklang.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hacklang.git'
```

Is it a problem with Composer settings?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using some third-party buildpack that can't pull its dependencies.

Why not use the official Heroku PHP buildpack with HHVM support? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#selecting-a-runtime-hhvm

Comment: This seems old, but it seems the official buildpack does not support HHVM any longer?  (Link is dead)